# SQL queries: find common parts which price has gone up from one type to another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in the database (big orange one) including parts and prices for two different type. I am looking to find the little orange table as result in summary:

**I am looking for common parts in both type R and O Where price has gone up from type O to type R.**

This is the script I tried but it is disconnected:

SELECT *FROM Table WHERE type='R'as a

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE type='O'as b

SELECT * FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.part = b.part
WHERE a.price < b.price

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  A query would help.  Also, what do the images represent?  Sample data as *text* and desired results as *text* are highly recommended.

Comment: You can to join the tables using *part* column, combined with `max(price)` and `group by` on other columns, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer Ideally supply sample data as a SQL script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer myself:

SELECT * INTO h
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.type='R';

SELECT * INTO b
FROM table AS tab
WHERE tab.type ='O';

SELECT h.type, h.part, h.price, b.price, (b.price - h.price) AS Gap

FROM h

INNER JOIN b ON h.part = b.part;

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know,

```
SELECT * FROM Table a, Table b 
WHERE a.type = 'R'
and b.type = 'O'
and a.part = b.part
and a.price < b.price;
```

Comment: We have just one table which is big orange one and I want to create the little orange table in the picture. I tried to create two sub-tables called a and b , a is all rows with type R and b is with type O. but it is not working. how do you define table a and b which they should be sub-table of the main table

Comment: It is called self joining, did not define 2 tables. Just join same table. try to run the query